# Java swing doInBackground, stopping program, and update GUI

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm new to java Swing, and I need to make some simple Java desktop app.
I have MainPanel in which I have SwingWorker with doInBackgroung in which I call service which calls a DAO that make a quering data from database. I also have a stop button which on click set worker.cancel(true), but the program is not stopping and I can not even close the window with X button.
I suppose that the proccessing is not stoped imidietly because the querying to database is not ended yet, but why cant I close the window?

This is the code:

```
worker = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

                long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                textArea.append("Starting...\n");

                generatingFilesService.genereteFiles(connectionDBFirst, connectionDBSecond, connectionDBThird,
                        date1, date2);
    
                long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                double time = (double) ((endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000_000);
                if (ConnectionDBFirst.flag != false) {
                    if (time < 60d) {
                        textArea.append("Genereting ended for " + time + " seconds\n");
                        textArea.setCaretPosition(MainPanel.textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                    } else {
                        textArea.append("Genereting ended for " + (time / 60) + " minutes\n");
                        textArea.setCaretPosition(MainPanel.textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }       
            
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    textArea.append("Stopping generating files...\n");
                    closeConnections();
                    logger.info(Messages.PROCCESS_INTERUPTED);
                } else 
                    closeConnections();
            }
        };worker.execute();
```

Stopping code:

```
if (e.getSource() == stop) {

        worker.cancel(true);

        stop.setEnabled(false);}
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answer and comments, here is the rest of the code:

```
public void genereteFiles(connectionDBFirst, connectionDBSecond, connectionDBThird,
                        date1, date2) {

    List<Person> persons1 = daoFirst.getPersons(connectionDBFirst, date1, date2);
        
    //here i want to update the textArea() that the daoFirst.getPersons() is done
    //but how to that without MainPanel.textArea.append(...);
    
    List<Person> persons2 = daoSecond.getPersons(connectionDBSecond, date1, date2);
    
    //here i want to update the textArea() that the daoSecond.getPersons() is done
    //but how to that without MainPanel.textArea.append(...);
    
    //same with daoThird

    genereteFilesService.createFiles(persons1, persons2, persons3);

    //update textArea() again

}
```

DAO code:

```
public List<Person> getPersons(connectionDBFirst, date1, date2) {

    //executeing sql query and geting the Persons
    //this takes long time, and from here I calculate 
    //percentage of persons fetched and I want to show the prcentage in textArea()
    //but how to do that without MainPanel.textArea.append(...);
}
```

Now, beside initial question, how can I use publish() and proccess() methods to update the textArea() from generateFiles() and DAO methods?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You're making Swing mutational calls from within the doInBackground method:

```
textArea.append(...);
```

And this breaks the threading rules and your program.

The solution is to not do this, and instead to `publish` the data that needs to be displayed and then `process` the information that was published via the publish/process method pair of the SwingWorker.

e.g., (code not tested):

```
worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        
        // textArea.append("Starting...\n");
        publish("Starting...\n");
        
        generatingFilesService.genereteFiles(connectionDBFirst, connectionDBSecond, connectionDBThird, date1, date2);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        double time = (double) ((endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000_000);
        if (ConnectionDBFirst.flag != false) {
            if (time < 60d) {
                // textArea.append("Genereting ended for " + time + " seconds\n");
                // textArea.setCaretPosition(MainPanel.textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                publish("Genereting ended for " + time + " seconds\n");
            } else {
                // textArea.append("Genereting ended for " + (time / 60) + " minutes\n");
                // textArea.setCaretPosition(MainPanel.textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                publish("Genereting ended for " + (time / 60) + " minutes\n");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }       

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String chunk : chunks) {
            textArea.append(chunk);
            textArea.setCaretPosition(MainPanel.textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }

// ....
}
worker.execute();
```

Comment: The problem with this (that I dont know how to solve) is that in genereteFiles() method I also need to update textArea() . Is it possible to update textArea() with publish() from generateFiles()? Also in genereteFiles() I call DAO methods in which also I need to update textArea()

Comment: repeating the gist of this answer: you __must not__ update any component from a background thread! Study the references (api doc and tutorial) I added to the question. When still stuck, come back with [mcve] demonstrating what __exactly__ is not working as expected.

Comment: Yes, I must not update  component from a background thread, but thats the problem. I have long proccessing database quey and I want to show some messages in textArea so the user will know the status of proccesing, and I dont know how to do this. Because its long proccesing I put it in doInBackground but as I asked, now I dont know how to show status messages to user and I cant use publish() beacuse the status is calculated in genereteFiles() and in other nested methods

Comment: Break your database process into several steps.  Each step gets its own SwingWorker.  As each step concludes, you can display the progress in a `JTextArea` using the SwingWorker `process` method.

Comment: @Ewe: we can only figure out an answer based on the specific information in your question. If you can figure out and express in your question exactly what data needs to be passed to the GUI and when, then we can provide more specific answers. Otherwise, until then, about the best any can do is to repeat that Swing GUI calls should not be made within a background thread, not unless those calls are explicitly queued onto the event dispatch thread by passing a Runnable into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`

Comment: I update the question with the rest of the code, hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for that, but please again check out the link that @kleopatra gave you above, which I'll repeat here: [mce]. The reason I am recommending that you check this out is that it is a useful tool both for helping you figure out your own debugging projects, but if you can create a decent MCE program, you can post it here and make it easier for *us* to figure out the bug. This is the type of code that would help you here the best. If anything in the link is confusing, please feel free to comment back.